# Razor with Url.Content helper is ending quotes at space in URL

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core

I'm using ASP.NET Core 2 with Razor to try and pass an image URL into the View via a ViewModel. Unfortunately, the image URL has spaces in it, which I don't have control over at the moment.

I have a file name like this (note the space):

```
https://example.com/images/file name.jpg
```

I'm using Razor to try and show the image like this:

```
<img src=@item.ImageUrl />
```

The output HTML looks like this:

```
<img src="https://example.com/images/file" name.jpg />
```

**Obviously this will not do!** I should mention, we know this all works when we use an image that has no spaces in the file name. Here are some ways I've tried to correct the issue:

Using `Url.Content` helper in Razor (this did not make a difference):

```
<img src=@Url.Content(item.ImageUrl) />
```

Using `System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode` when populating the ViewModel (this results in a "double-encoding" error):

```
myViewModel.ImageUrl = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(someUrl);
```

My goal is to get the URL encoded properly (no "double-encoding" and no truncating at the space in the input string). How can I achieve this goal?

Comment: Producing invalid urls is not a very noble goal... But you can always use `@Html.Raw(...)` to output exactly what you think you should.

Comment: Are you sure that you don't actually want `<img src="@item.ImageUrl" />`? You seem to be missing the quotes. Also, `System.Web` is for old ASP.NET, not for ASP.NET Core

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov this is why I tried using `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` but I'm not sure why it gave me the "double-encoding" error.

Comment: Thank you @CamiloTerevinto ... that is the solution I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Razor will attempt to create valid HTML, so when it sees a space it automatically closes the quotation marks, so:

```
@{string img = "a a.jpg";}
<img src=@img />
```

Gets rendered as

```
<img src="a "a.jpg /> // of course invalid
```

So, you need to be sure you include your quotation marks, then Razor will use them:

```
<img src="@img" />
```

Which gets rendered as

```
<img src="a a.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
<img src="@Html.Raw(item.ImageUrl)" />
```

but I agree that using invalid URLs (with spaces) doesn't seem very useful in the long run.

Comment: I rephrased the "goal" in my original post based on feedback in the comments.  As you say, the goal should not be to form an invalid URL; it should be to get the URL encoded the right way.  Sorry for the misdirection.